# Articles About Data Acquisition from Existing Sources

Tags: database, report, business-intelligence

I'm writing a report about best practices for data acquisition from existing sources. However, I'm having trouble finding many articles or papers about what I need. Most of what I find is either data acquisition from the source, e.g. a weather station, or gloss over really quickly the part where you talk to a different team about getting access to their data.

Esentially, I'm looking for articles that list some good questions to ask when you talk to other teams in your orginization about getting access to their data so the BI's can use it. Even a search term I could use that would better describe what I'm looking for. At first I thought maybe data wrangling could be it, but all my searches yield articles about manipulating the data to what you need.

To recap, I'm after some pointers to articles or search terms I could use to find the articles that cover a set of best practices that you should follow when talking to other departments about getting access to their databases for BI purposes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend paying attention to your search engine, there are many more of them than just Google. In my practice, there are often cases when it was possible to find rare information that could not be found by one search engine, but managed by others.

Here are the results of the query "how the analyst communicates with other departments" from Google search:

A set of tips for a communication analyst -
https://inside.getyourguide.com/blog/2020/7/28/10-tips-on-effective-communication-in-business-intelligence

A set of tips for an analyst on interdepartmental communication -
https://www.phocassoftware.com/business-intelligence-blog/four-ways-to-promote-interdepartmental-communication

An article about communication-oriented modeling to improve the efficiency of an analyst -
https://www.crystalloids.com/news/fully-communication-oriented-information-modelling

And here are the results of the same query but in DuckDuckGo:

A set of general interdepartmental communication tips -
https://www.themuse.com/advice/how-to-communicate-better-with-other-departments

An article on effective communication for an analyst - https://www.northeastern.edu/graduate/blog/communicating-with-data/

A set of tips for an analyst to improve communication skills -
https://www.modernanalyst.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/115/ID/1994/10-Ways-to-Hone-Your-Communication-Skills-as-a-Business-Analyst.aspx

And these are only 2 search engines, and there are also Bing, Ecosia, Yandex, Startpage. With the right query and a variety of search tools, you can get any information of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using different search engines. I tend to use solely Duckduckgo and didn't even think of looking for others.